# Error R10 (Boot timeout) While deploying express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

Okay, So I already went through all answers from SO and other websites for this problem but it didn't solved.
I have developed a small express app with ES6 syntax so after deploying it to heroku i am getting this error.

LOGS :

```
2021-04-09T12:14:14.688546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-09T12:14:17.094473+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:17.094495+00:00 app[web.1]: > todo@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-09T12:14:17.094496+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build && node ./build/app.js
2021-04-09T12:14:17.094496+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:17.415529+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:17.415540+00:00 app[web.1]: > todo@1.0.0 build /app
2021-04-09T12:14:17.415541+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run clean && npm run build-babel
2021-04-09T12:14:17.415541+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:17.774142+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:17.774147+00:00 app[web.1]: > todo@1.0.0 clean /app
2021-04-09T12:14:17.774148+00:00 app[web.1]: > rm -rf build && mkdir build
2021-04-09T12:14:17.774148+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:18.129225+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:18.129247+00:00 app[web.1]: > todo@1.0.0 build-babel /app
2021-04-09T12:14:18.129248+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel -d ./build ./src -s
2021-04-09T12:14:18.129248+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-09T12:14:19.523820+00:00 app[web.1]: Successfully compiled 10 files with Babel (1213ms).
2021-04-09T12:14:22.100639+00:00 app[web.1]: [INFO] Connected to DB
2021-04-09T12:15:14.832949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-04-09T12:15:14.869178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-04-09T12:15:14.978950+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-04-09T12:15:15.039050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

This is the scripts in `Package.json` file

```json
 "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./src -s",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/app.js",
  },
```

After running npm start locally it creates the app.js file inside build/ folder. Now according the the logs I am able to connect to the mongdb but the app is not listening to the PORT.

I checked locally too and it didn't worked. Here is the built app.js file from build folder.

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = void 0;

var _express = _interopRequireDefault(require("express"));

var _passport = _interopRequireDefault(require("passport"));

var _connectDb = _interopRequireDefault(require("./connectDb"));

var _routes = _interopRequireDefault(require("./constants/routes"));

var _cors = _interopRequireDefault(require("cors"));

var app = (0, _express["default"])();
app.use((0, _cors["default"])()); // Load dotenv file in devlopment

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
} // Middlewares


app.use(_express["default"].json());
(0, _connectDb["default"])(); // Initializing passport

require('./routes/authentication/passportConfig')(_passport["default"]); // TODO turn this into ES6 syntax


app.use(_passport["default"].initialize());
app.use(_passport["default"].session());
app.get('/', function (_req, res) {
  res.send("hello world");
}); // Routes

app.use('/auth', _routes["default"].AUTHENTICATION);

var _default = app;
exports["default"] = _default;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

If i add this to the build/app.js file and run `node ./build/app.js`

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(`Live at ${process.env.PORT || 5000}`);
})
```

It works. The console statement gets printed.
I am struck at how to solve this issue and deploy it to the heroku.

EDIT :

I referred this article to deploy ES6 JS to heroku [How to deploy ES6 Nodejs & Express to Heroku](https://medium.com/@kimtnguyen/how-to-deploy-es6-node-js-express-back-end-to-heroku-7e6743e8d2ff)
Thanks in advance.

As suggested by answer [Answer 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67023663/11283638) I increased the timing to 120 seconds but still app is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously receiving an R10 (Boot Timeout) error because the app fails to bind to Heroku's Port in 60 seconds.

Try maybe to increase the boot time limit using Heroku's `Boot Timeout Tool`:

https://tools.heroku.support/limits/boot_timeout

You can read more on this support page:

https://help.heroku.com/W5ETWBQB/why-is-my-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: Yup i did it. I increased it to 120 seconds but still the error persists. The issue is not with timing i guess. If you read the question i mentioned that app.listen is not added to app.js file after building